# android api 30 Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: java, android

My app worked fine at api29. Now getting this native error. No clue otherwise.

```
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREPERF for destination cct
```

V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lDY2traUg4aTJaQVJ3T3MxTEV6RktsZDE1YU9HOG96S28=) with jobId=-546033166 in 30000ms(Backend next call timestamp 1639520060629). Attempt 1
D/mainact: buildDisplayDataBase:
A/libc: fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 75, expected to be unowned, actually owned by FILE* 0xf108246c
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 20661 (eymoreau.fitlog), pid 20661 (eymoreau.fitlog)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:60917', transport: 'socket'

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying images try eliminating them to see of it fixes the error.

It did for me and I ended up changing my image loading from:

```
mainMenu_viewHolder.getImageView().setImageResource(R.drawable.gear);
```

to...

```
Bitmap checkImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(fragment.getResources(), R.drawable.check);
            mainMenu_viewHolder.getImageView().setImageBitmap(checkImg);
```

The issue is buried very deep so if this doesn't work for you don't try stepping through your code or researching the native error. It will be wasted time. Just disable your fragments entire view structure and add back in piece by piece.